# refund_status NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER, paypal response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using this gem for payments in my rails app:

https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment

I can not make a refund, I get the next message in response log:

```
...refund_status="NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER">]> response_envelope=#<Hashie::Rash ack="Success"....
```

I am using the `pay_key` for make a refund.

**Its possible fix this error?**

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the problem was, For a receiver to grant permission to refund to the API Caller:

Login to www.paypal.com (For Sandbox: www.sandbox.paypal.com - Make sure you are already signed in https://developer.paypal.com) and login with the receiver account. Goto Profile -> API Access -> Grant API Permission -> Input the API Caller (Example: May6_1307031077_biz_api1.paypal.com) in Third Party Permission Username textbos and click Lookup button -> Enable checkbox for "Issue a refund for a specific transaction" and click Add button.

This is how receiver can grant permission to API Caller.

Once this is enabled, the refund should work.

Founded in https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/adaptive-refund-notprocessed

### Edited.......

You can see on https://www.x.com/devzone/articles/paypal-permissions-and-advantages-integrating-permissions-api If you need make this feature with Api you can use this gem:

https://github.com/moshbit/paypal_permissions

Thank you very much!

Comment: If someone will not be able to find "API Access" button like me )) here is the solution via images: http://support.inksoft.com/knowledgebase/articles/293226-setting-up-paypal-express

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, I am sending and wanting refund back payment using paypal adaptive method. To do this, I am going to Add New Third Party Permission. But on this page, paypal asking for third party api username. I don't know from where I can get this username. I have tried to search on internet but nothing got. Can anyone help to get from where I can get this username. I am implementing this functionality in Prestashop.

Comment: hi @hyperrrjas where we will get api caller ex:-May6_1307031077_biz_api1.paypal.com ?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and my issue could not be resolved by the accepted solution. My problem was that I sent money from a merchant account to a seller account and was trying to refund the transaction, but there is (currently) no way to grant API permissions from a personal account to allow the refund transaction to go through. I just called Paypal, and they said that there's no way to complete the refund I was attempting to do, but since I only needed the refund for testing purposes (to make sure there was always money in my merchant account), they suggested that I instead just send an equal payment from my personal account back to my merchant account. I hope this helps someone.