# Can I change displayOptions.businessName on an adaptive payment preapproval?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I'm completing Paypal adaptive payments on behalf of another party. I would like the transaction to appear as if it's being done by another party, not by me as a facilitator. That is possible with chained adaptive payments and setting the displayOptions.businessName using the `SetPaymentOptions` endpoint. The workflow for this is `cmd=_ap-payment`. However, I cannot issue a refund for such a transaction without additional permissions from the recepient (see here: [refund_status NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER, paypal response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516334/refund-status-no-api-access-to-receiver-paypal-response) ). Now, it's possible for me to use the workflow `cmd=_ap-preapproval`, but in that case I cannot use `SetPaymentOptions` to change the business name.

Is it possible for me to both be able to refund a transaction, and change the business name, using adaptive payments in Paypal, without requiring extra permissions from the recipient?